# Maximum number of digits should not be more than 10 digits under Phone field

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to validate phone number with the following jQuery, where customer should enter 10 digit number only. I am unable to get any alert with the following code, any mistake am I doing?. Thank you!! in advance guys.

````
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $('textarea').keyup(function() {
          var cs = $(this).val().length;
          $('#Phone').text(cs);
          if(cs.length < 10){
              alert("Phone number must contains 10 digits ");
          }
      });
  </script> ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('textarea').keyup(function() {
```

apex:inputText is an input, not a textarea. Also, users will have to click in to the field after every keystroke, not a friendly experience. Try using blur instead.

```
    $('#Phone').text(cs);
```

This code doesn't do anything. Any Visualforce element with an ID will have its ID modified to be unique. You need to query for it using something like:

```
$('input[id$=Phone]')
```

---

```
if(cs.length < 10){
```

cs.length would be undefined, because it's already a number.

---

A closer approximation would be:

```
$('[input$=Phone]').blur(function() {
  if($(this).val().match(/\d+/)[0].length < 10) {
    alert('Please enter at least 10 digits');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you!! sfdcfox it showed a way to my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend re-assessing your current approach and consider using the  [apex:inputText](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputText.htm) available attributes for what you are attempting to do.

Then, you might want to validate the following:

> 1. Is keyup firing the event?
> 2. is cs defined?
> 3. is your if condition applied?

These are basic troubleshooitng questions you need to validate for determining why your code is not working and provide the community when posting these types of questions.